# Force point (“.”) as decimal separator while using Android DataBinding

Tags: java, android, android-databinding

I am trying to format a double from API so it only shows the first 2 decimals. Also, I am doing this using `DataBinding`. When I do it this way, it works:

```
android:text='@{String.format("%.2f", cartItem.totalPrice)}'
```

But, this will use comma `,` as a decimal separator. When I try to force it to use point `.` as decimal separator I can't build the project because I get a `DataBinding` error. This is what I'm trying to do:

```
android:text='@{String.format(Locale.ROOT, "%.2f", cartItem.totalPrice)}'
```

Comment: I assume that you just forgot to import Locale. Try `<import type="java.util.Locale"/>` in the data section.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> But, this will use comma , as a decimal separator.

You cannot use comma here. This dot is NOT a decimal separator character but part of format specifier regarding output precision ([see docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Formatter.html#detail)). So once you got your output, you simply need to replace `.` with `,` like:

```
android:text='@{String.format("%.2f", cartItem.totalPrice).replace(".", ",")}'
```

to end up with comma separator.

Comment: Actually, the output was placing `,` by default, I needed to replace the `,` with `.` However, thanks to your answer, I did it.